# MySQL set storing

Tags: mysql, recursion, set, normalization

I have a couple of tables in a web application I'm coding in PHP, and I would like to know if this would be good pratice.

```
CREATE TABLE `products`(
  `product_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `variations` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `variations`(
  `variation_id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `kind` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`variation_id`)
)
```

For example, a product will be:

```
1,'Cup','1,2,3'
```

While a variation would be:

```
1,'Green','Color'
2,'Glass','Texture'
3,'Blue','Color'
```

such that many products could have the same colors/textures. The issue I find is that I cannot fit this into a single query that would return the data as:

```
1,'Cup','1,Green,Color-2,Glass,Texture-3,Blue,Color'
```

And afterwards parse this accordingly to display an image of each variation.

Is a stored function that returns that format the best idea? Or should I normalize even further, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the wise thing to to is add another table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_variations`(
  `product_id` int NOT NULL,
  `variation_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`, `variation_id`)
);
```

From there, a simple query joining the three tables will give you the results you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(variation_id, ', ', name, ', ', kind SEPARATOR '-')
FROM    products
INNER JOIN
        variations
ON      FIND_IN_SET(variation_id, variations)
GROUP BY
        product_id
```

As it's a many-to-many relationship, it's better to have a third table:

```
CREATE TABLE product_variations
(
   product_id INT NOT NULL,
   variation_id INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (product_id, variation_id)
);
```

Comment: Would this be better than the answer above? I'm not very familiar with MySQL's performance.

Comment: No, @Seb's answer is great. My answer is good only if you already have a schema you need to live with. If you can change the schema and add the third table then do it for the God's sake.